# Make Firefox's "System theme" darker

Tags: gnome, firefox, themes, gtk, yaru

I managed to get the close button of Firefox to look like my Ubuntu's (22.04) Yaru-dark. However, it's a bit lighter than the system's dark theme (especially the toolbar). Would there be a way to tweak Firefox's "System theme" theme to be a bit darker? Thanks in advance!

Here's a screenshot (since I don't have enough reputation I can't add it directly here): [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5aHW.png)

Comment: Sounds like a good question to ask the people that make Firefox.